# Pra que serve .this em java

Tags: java

Ola, entao, estou comecando no java e gostaria de entender melhor o que é .this.
Imagino que tenha algo a ver com a classe atual ou algo do genero. Mas não tenho certeza. Vou postar uma parte do meu codigo que .this esta contido

```
   class Conta {  
   int numero;
   String dono;
   double saldo;
   double limite; 
  // Os metodos que ultilizam o .this
   boolean saca(double valor) {
         if (this.saldo < valor) {
           return false;
         }
         else {
           this.saldo = this.saldo - valor;
           return true;
         }
   }
      void deposita(double quantidade) {
         this.saldo += quantidade;
   }
}
```

Tem a public class tambem que só está dando valor as variaveis criadas na classe Conta

Answer (score 2):

Isso é para diferenciar quando o método tem o mesmo nome de parametro que a class, no seu codigo isso não acontece, então não tem necessidade do this, se vc tivesse algum atributo na classe com o nome de valor, ai aquele metodo precisaria de um this.valor, pra dizer que vc quer alterar apenas o atributo daquela instancia e não da classe

Pelo visto ta estudando pelas apostilas da caelum, logo logo vc vai entender bem isso, esse metodos iram crescer bem ainda rsrs

mas ao grosso modo eh isso, se seu metodo passa parametro com o mesmo nome de um atributo da classe, então para se referenciar a aquela instancia do metodo, se usa o this., senão fizer isso, java ira entender que quer alterar o atributo da classe